# how to create an app tour/walkthrough in cordova?

Tags: jquery, css, html, cordova, cordova-plugins

> I want to create an app tour/walkthrough for my cordova project.  I
>   have tried bootstrap tour ,but it is not like native android
>   tour/walkthrough .

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear, but if I get it correctly you can use this codepen

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('intro', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/intro.html',
    controller: 'IntroCtrl'
  })
  .state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

})

.controller('IntroCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
 
  // Called to navigate to the main app
  $scope.startApp = function() {
    $state.go('main');
  };
  $scope.next = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
  };
  $scope.previous = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.previous();
  };

  // Called each time the slide changes
  $scope.slideChanged = function(index) {
    $scope.slideIndex = index;
  };
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  console.log('MainCtrl');
  
  $scope.toIntro = function(){
    $state.go('intro');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}
.slider {
  height: 100%;
}
.slider-slide {
  padding-top: 80px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;

  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 300;
}

#logo {
  margin: 30px 0px;
}

#list {
  width: 170px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#list ol {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#list ol li {
  text-align: left;
  list-style: decimal;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.button.ng-hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Ionic App</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="ionicApp">

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-light">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


    <script id="templates/intro.html" type="text/ng-template"> 
      <ion-view view-title="Intro">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
          <button class="button button-positive button-clear no-animation"
                  ng-click="startApp()" ng-show="!slideIndex">
            Skip Intro
          </button>
          <button class="button button-positive button-clear no-animation"
                  ng-click="previous()" ng-show="slideIndex > 0">
            Previous Slide
          </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right"> 
          <button class="button button-positive button-clear no-animation"
                  ng-click="next()" ng-show="slideIndex != 2">
            Next
          </button>
          <button class="button button-positive button-clear no-animation"
                  ng-click="startApp()" ng-show="slideIndex == 2">
            Start using MyApp
          </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)">
          <ion-slide>
            <h3>Thank you for choosing the Awesome App!</h3>
            <div id="logo">
              <img src="http://code.ionicframework.com/assets/img/app_icon.png">
            </div>
            <p>
              We've worked super hard to make you happy.
            </p>
            <p>
              But if you are angry, too bad.
            </p>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <h3>Using Awesome</h3>
            
            <div id="list">
              <h5>Just three steps:</h5>
              <ol>
                <li>Be awesome</li>
                <li>Stay awesome</li>
                <li>There is no step 3</li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <h3>Any questions?</h3>
            <p>
              Too bad!
            </p>
          </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/main.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view hide-back-button="true" view-title="Awesome">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <h1>Main app here</h1>
          <button class="button" ng-click="toIntro()">Do Tutorial Again</button>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The original pen is for ionic team http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/AjgEB

Comment: this code is for ionic ..i am developing in cordova